# How to transfer drop-down values to List-box control using java script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I am trying to tranfer dropdown data to listbox using javascript and below is my asp.net CascadingDropDown  drop-down control and filling drop down using Webservice

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Trainer" runat="server" required="required" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select Trainer" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>

   <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown7" runat="server" Category="subproduct"
     Enabled="True" LoadingText="Loading Trainer..." ParentControlID="ddl_ProjectType" PromptText=" 
    - Select Trainer -"                                                                                    
    ServiceMethod="GetDropDowntrainer" ServicePath="Getdropdowns.asmx" 
   TargetControlID="ddl_Trainer"></cc1:CascadingDropDown>
```

I want same data of dropdown into listbox control using Javascript, why i should write another webservice and below listbox control

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lst_OtherTrainers" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control"> 
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: on click get selected index add new list item to list box

Comment: I am talking about using java-script to fill list-box, not drop down-list select index change. @Sanguine

Comment: Not select index changed... When you change the value of the selected item in the list box, use a JS function to add a new ListBox item to the ListBox, or select the one that matches it - your question was vague

Comment: Please add some code to show us your attempt and where the problem occurs.